# Error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Stylesheet.create') (Device"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> I am new to react native and need help. I created two components one
> is for TextInput and another for button, I imported the Button
> component in textInput and it show error. can someone help me figure
> out the error I made here.  I am getting error undefined is not an
> object(evalutaing;?_reactnative,stylesheet.create')*
> and folder structure in the picture attached
> this is button Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Stylesheet } from 'react-native';

export const Button = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={\[styles(size).radius, style\]}>
      <Text style={\[styles.text, textStyle\]}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
**error is likely to be here**
const styles = (size) => Stylesheet.create({
    radius: {
      borderRadius: size / 3,
      width: size,
      hieght: size,
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderColor: 'white',
    },
    text: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
  });
```

**this is textInput component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

import {Button} from '../components/Button';
// You can import from local files

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

export const Something = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}> input something here</Text>
        <TextInput />
        <Button title="+" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,

    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: please add your error log to help others answer your question.

Comment: it should be StyleSheet.create, check the spelling

Answer (score 0):

Mispelled height maybe?

```js
const styles = (size) => Stylesheet.create({
    radius: {
      borderRadius: size / 3,
      width: size,
      hieght: size, <-------------------- hieght
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderColor: 'white',
    },
    text: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
  });
```

Comment: and if i dont import button import it working fine

Comment: Just for fun - try and move your button import right below your react import